# javascript window.var_name vs window['var_name']

Tags: javascript, window

Which of these variants is more accepted by most browsers or more recommended to use ?

```
window.var_name;
//or
window['var_name'];
```

Comment: the will return exactly the same result. Look up object vs array notation and the difference between objects and arrays in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make any difference - both of those ways are the ways of getting the value of the object by name.The second one is in case you want to get the value by a name which is stored in the variable (or a result of an expression).

In your case, the object is window, so you could either get that value with just `var_name`.

```js
var var_name = "test";
console.log(var_name);
console.log(window.var_name);
console.log(window['var_name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, it depends on coding style.

First one can be use when you know your variable name at development time e.g;

```
window.var_name;
```

while second is useful if you get variable name at run time e.g;

```
window[getVarNameDynamically()];
```